# Arcpy ArcMap mosaic use different raster whenever nodata value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, mosaic, nodata

I am using ArcPy in ArcMap and have multiple Rasters (Landsat imagery) taken from a given area (Image 1). 
[image: All rasters set next to each other]

My final goal is to create a cloud free image of the complete area. Since the Rasters contain clouds, I first used the BQA given for the data and classified clouds, background, etc for each Raster as nodata. I am doing this to later replace these nodata entries with the entries of other Rasters taken of the same area. When I merge my Rasters with (composites is a list of Rasters)

```
arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(composites, os.getcwd(), mosaic_name, number_of_bands = number_bands, mosaic_method = 'MAXIMUM')
```

I obtain a merged image that uses the pixel values of the underlying Raster if its classified as nodata in the above Raster (Image 2).

[image: Rasters combined with MosaicToNewRaster_Management directly]

This is exactly the behavior I want to achieve. However, the disadvantage of this approach is that the code is not doing any color balancing, which I require. When I create a mosaic separately and do color balancing

```py
mosaic = arcpy.CreateMosaicDataset_management("C:/Users/georg/OneDrive/Dokumente/ArcGIS/Default.gdb",  mosaic_name, arcpy.Describe(composites[0]).spatialReference,  num_bands = number_bands)
arcpy.SetRasterProperties_management(mosaic,nodata="1 0;2 0;3 0;4 0;5 0;6 0;7 0")
arcpy.DefineMosaicDatasetNoData_management(mosaic, number_bands, "ALL_BANDS '0'")
arcpy.SetMosaicDatasetProperties_management(mosaic, mosaic_operator='MAX')
arcpy.AddRastersToMosaicDataset_management(mosaic, "Raster Dataset", composites)
arcpy.BuildFootprints_management(mosaic)
arcpy.BuildSeamlines_management(mosaic)
arcpy.BuildPyramidsandStatistics_management(mosaic)
arcpy.ColorBalanceMosaicDataset_management(mosaic, "DODGING", "COLOR_GRID")
arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(mosaic, os.getcwd(), mosaic_name+".tif", number_of_bands = number_bands, mosaic_method = 'MAXIMUM')
```

the final image classifies a pixel as nodata if the top Raster is nodata at this Pixel (Image 3), whereas it should be using a Pixel from the underlying Raster in such a case. How do I fix this problem? I tried many different settings, but none did work.
[image: Manual mosaic creation propagates nodata pixels.]

Comment: I'd split originals into bands first and mosaic them.

Comment: @FelixIP why do you suggest this?

Comment: Because 1 band rasters understand no data better than multiband.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why, but this made me solve my problem:

```
arcpy.BuildSeamlines_management(mosaic, computation_method = 'COPY_FOOTPRINT')
```

i.e. I changed the computation method of the seamlines to 'COPY_FOOTPRINT'. I think the default computation method created mostly non-overlapping seamlines and then relied for each pixel on a single raster. However, this is not the behavior I wanted, since I wanted to deliberately use my mosaic method to determine what pixels to use.

Bottom-line: building seamlines may conflict with the mosaic method chosen.